# Polling in lightning component

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting, lightning-aura-components

What's the best way to implement polling inside Lightning component. I'd like to update my component every 5-10 seconds, calling backend (i.e. Apex class) to obtain new data for rendering. Seems like there is no **apex:actionPoller** analogue in Lightning.

Comment: do you mean apex:actionPoller instead of apex:actionFunction?

Comment: Yes, sure. Sorry for typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this truly a polling event, or could it handled via PushTopics? If it is based on the value changing on a record, consider using PushTopics.

For polling, setTimeout and setInterval work, just be sure to use $A.run when making calls to actions, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good example of setInterval. I found it helpful.

[Calling Apex method at regular interval from Lightning Component](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/calling-apex-method-at-regular-interval-from-lightning-component/)